# repository always null after initilization of testing containers

Tags: mockito, testcontainers

I am attempting to use TestingContainers. I was able to get it to run but my tests are always null. I am trying to avoid mocking but rather having real data.

Repository

```
@Sql("classpath:data.sql")
class OrderDataRepositoryTest extends AbstractTestConfiguration {

    //@Mock
    @MockBean
    //@Autowired
    private OrderDataRepository orderRepository;

    private AutoCloseable closeable;

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        closeable = MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @AfterEach
    void closeService() throws Exception {
        closeable.close();
    }

    @Test
    void getAllUsersTest() {
        List<Order> orders = orderRepository.findAll();
        orders.toString();
    }

}
```

config

```
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@Testcontainers
public abstract class AbstractTestConfiguration {

    @Container
    private MySQLContainer database = new MySQLContainer("mysql:8.0");


    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertTrue(database.isRunning());
    }


}
```

main

```
@SpringBootTest
@Sql("classpath:init.sql")
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.yml")
class TentingContainerApplicationTests {

}
```

application.properties

```
spring:
  application:
  datasource:
      url: jdbc:mysql:8.0:///test?TC_INITSCRIPT=file:src/main/resources/init.sql
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

The commented out

```
//@Mock
@MockBean
//@Autowired
```

is what I tried. Of course mock works out but I want real data for the @services and @repository classes.

advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test your database-related code in isolation (I assume you're using Spring Data JPA) then `@DataJpaTest` fits perfectly.

This annotation will create a [sliced Spring context for you that contains only persistence relevant beans](https://rieckpil.de/test-your-spring-boot-jpa-persistence-layer-with-datajpatest/) like: `DataSource`, `EntityManager`, `YourRepository`. This doesn't include your service classes, your `@Component` classes, or `@RestController`.

By default, this annotation tries to configure an embedded in-memory database as the `DataSource`. We can override this (and you already did with some of your code examples) behavior to use Testcontainers:

```
@DataJpaTest
@Testcontainers
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
class OrderDataRepositoryTest {
 
  @Container
  static MySQLContainer database = new MySQLContainer("mysql:8.0");
 
  @DynamicPropertySource
  static void setDatasourceProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry propertyRegistry) {
    propertyRegistry.add("spring.datasource.url", database::getJdbcUrl);
    propertyRegistry.add("spring.datasource.password", database::getPassword);
    propertyRegistry.add("spring.datasource.username", database::getUsername);
  }
 
  @Autowired
  private OrderDataRepository orderRepository;
 
  @Test
  void shouldReturnOrders() {

  }
}
```

If you want to write another test that includes all your beans and also starts the embedded servlet container, take a [look at @SpringBootTest for writing integration tests](https://rieckpil.de/guide-to-springboottest-for-spring-boot-integration-tests/).

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Testcontainers

class MyIntegrationTest {
 
  @Container
  static MySQLContainer database = new MySQLContainer("mysql:8.0");
 
  @DynamicPropertySource
  static void setDatasourceProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry propertyRegistry) {
    propertyRegistry.add("spring.datasource.url", database::getJdbcUrl);
    propertyRegistry.add("spring.datasource.password", database::getPassword);
    propertyRegistry.add("spring.datasource.username", database::getUsername);
  }

@Autowired
private ServiceA serviceA;

@Autowired
private OrderDataRepository orderDataRepository;
```

}

When working with a Spring TestContext for your test and Mockito, make sure to understand the [difference between @Mock and @MockBean](https://rieckpil.de/difference-between-mock-and-mockbean-spring-boot-applications/).